# Is there any ANTLR4 vim syntax file?

Tags: vim, antlr

I was only able to find this one (https://github.com/rollxx/vim-antlr), but it was made for version 3. Does anyone knows where I can find proper syntax for version 4?

Comment: Did you consider working with the author to update his syntax file?

Comment: The user looks somewhat inactive for like, a year; and I have no experience with syntax files :\

Answer (score 8):

There's another fork of [rollx/vim-antlr](https://github.com/rollxx/vim-antlr) that supports ANTLR4: [dylon/vim-antlr](https://github.com/dylon/vim-antlr)

Answer (score 2):

The fork that [pascal mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23448071/578288) is now unavailable, but I found another working one in GitHub’s [list of forks of rollxx/vim-antlr](https://github.com/rollxx/vim-antlr/network). That fork is [jrozner/vim-antlr](https://github.com/jrozner/vim-antlr).

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork that supports version 4: [blinks/vim-antlr](https://github.com/blinks/vim-antlr)

Comment: Looks like this fork is dead, now.